# SwiftJSON turning my data into null

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJSON (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to handle my JSON data. I've spent hours on trial and error and can't figure out what is going wrong. I can't provide the actual JSON I am trying to parse, but I have some examples to compare by contrast.

This example I found works and parses just fine in my project (a working example):

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://express.heartrails.com/api/json?method=getPrefectures")
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
if data != nil {
    var json = JSON(data: data!)
    println(json)
    println(json["response"]["prefecture"][0])
}
```

Now my data I am receiving back does not work with SwiftyJSON, converting the data into the SwiftyJSON type turns it into null (fake example):

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://myjsonurl.com")
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
if data != nil {
    var json = JSON(data: data!)
    println(json)
}
```

Returns null. But I know I am actually getting the correct data when I print the data with this:

```
println(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

And the entire JSON appears in the console.

So I know that SwiftyJSON has been implemented correctly and my code should be correct. Is there something wrong in the backend? The format of the JSON I am using *seems* to be correct.

Comment: Does it work if you use NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData? https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:

Comment: Check that your JSON format is ok with http://jsonlint.com or  NSJSONSerialization's `isValidJSONObject(_:)` method.

Comment: Oh man, I am getting back that the JSON isn't valid. Pieces of data in the JSON don't have a value. I would've assumed that it would return nothing for that particular piece, but apparently without every piece of data having a default value the entire JSON is invalid?

Comment: Check for fragments, missing commas, unclosed brackets and more importantly escape the quote signs whenever not intended.